# HTML5 input date placeholder in Arabic browser

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

HTML5 input date placeholder in Arabic browser (after changing the display  language to be Arabic) is totally reversed and looks unacceptable

[image]

and this is the markup for each one:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.EndDate" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"
                               autocomplete="off" type="date" id="endDate" max="2200-12-31">
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                        <label>إلى</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.StartDate" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"
                               autocomplete="off" type="date" max="2200-12-31" id="startDate">
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                        <label>من</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

How to fix the revered placeholder text??

Comment: What's unacceptable about it? Arabic is a right to left language, so this UI is expected

Comment: The Arabic text is unacceptable, it should be 
يوم-شهر-سنة
not 
موي-رهش-ةنس
the arabic letters sequence is totally reversed, just like you say in English:  "yad-htnom-raey" instead of "day-month-year"

Comment: Understood. We can't really help with that without seeing the full CSS/HTML causing the issue - or even where the arabic text is coming from as it's not in the markup example.

Comment: @ethry Please read my reply to Rory, just above you. I explained why not acceptable

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan
Edited for Full Markup ^

Comment: @ethry 
Arabic is not meant to be like that.
I succeeeded to solve it by replacing HTML5 input date with JQueryUI datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to solve, by changing the control to be text and then applying bootstrap datepicker library on it , Just like in this demo:

https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/localization.html

```js
$("#endDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'm-d-yy' }).datepicker($.datepicker.regional["ar"]);
$("#startDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'm-d-yy' }).datepicker($.datepicker.regional["ar"]);
```

```html
<input class="form-control" lang="en-us" asp-for="@Model.EndDate" type="text" placeholder="شهر-يوم-سنة" autocomplete="off" id="endDate" max="2200-12-31">
                                   
<input class="form-control" lang="en-us" asp-for="@Model.StartDate" type="text" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" autocomplete="off" max="2200-12-31" id="startDate" value="">
```

Comment: That is a jQueryUI datepicker, though?

Comment: Yes, exactly it is.
Edited for changes to solve